# How to find set functions that satisfy two of the three properties (probability)

Tags: probability-distributions

We know from the theory the following properties:

1. 0≤P(A)≤1 for every A
2. P(Ω)=1
3. If A1, A2,...An are mutually exclusive then P(A1 ∪ A2 ∪ ...An)= P(A1)+P(A2)+...+P(An)

In the exercise, it is given that **Ω= {α,β}** and **ΣΩ={ Ø , Ω, {α}, {β} }**

It is asked:

i) to find a set function **Q: ΣΩ → R** that satisfies 1 and 2 but not 3

ii) to find a set function **Q: ΣΩ → R** that satisfies 1 and 3 but not 2

I tried to start it by saying that: P({a})= q and P({b})=1-q , but i find it impossible not to meet one of these properties while meeting the other two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$i)$
$Q(\emptyset)=0, Q(\Omega)=1, Q(\{\alpha\})=0.9, Q(\{\beta\})=0.9.$

$ii)$
$Q(\emptyset)=0, Q(\Omega)=0, Q(\{\alpha\})=0, Q(\{\beta\})=0.$

Comment: How is this true?
Given that the powerset only contains two elements ({α} and {β}), shouldn't it be:
Q({α})=0.9       Q({β})=1-Q({α})=1-0.9=0.1  ?

Comment: The powerset contains four elements and $Q$ does not have to satisfy your additional property. Notice that $you$ assign values.